# A moderator declined my migration flag—what are the policies for flagging questions for migration?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, declined-flags, migration

A *lot* of questions get asked on Meta about declined moderator flags. I don't really want to be one of "those people" who asks about every little possible mistake, but I am a little curious about this particular instance.

The question in discussion is here: [Creating an append function in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29137103/465378)

To me, this *perfectly* fits the bill for migration to Code Review.

- This is a good, well-described, well-written question.
- The code provided in the question *already works*, and the OP is just asking for specific improvements.<sup>†</sup>

I flagged for a request for migration, but (a number of days later) the flag was declined. There are a few explanations I could come up with for this.

- The question could have been misinterpreted as the OP asking to finish broken code. That wasn't the case, but it isn't perfectly clear.
- Though the question was originally flagged when it had no answers, a short time after I flagged it, an answer was posted and subsequently accepted.
- Perhaps the most compelling reason—while this question would fit very nicely on Code Review, it isn't necessarily *off-topic on Stack Overflow*.

In the event that the flag was declined due to one of the first two reasons, that would seem like a simple mistake. It happens.

On the other hand, it seems more likely to me that the third possibility is correct. This raises the question: should I ever request migration to a site that might be a "better fit" if the question is on-topic on SO? I don't think it could *hurt*, but I'd understand if that were the policy.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>(I guess one could argue that the "improvements" involve too much new code rather than a review of existing code, but I've personally answered questions on CR that involved much more rewriting.)</sub>

Comment: Extremely related [What questions are suitable for migration to Code Review, and how does the process work?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1687)

Comment: @Braiam Yep. The only point that could be disputed would be point number 2, the one about off-topicness on the original site.

Comment: @whispers: Such ignorant comments only go to show further that we have a serious problem with education among the low-rep users.

Comment: I have to agree with @whispers. I'm extremely reluctant to even ask a question on SO anymore due to the almost certain negative comments and down-voting. I don't mind a question or answer getting downvoted if the person leaves a short comment to say why they have downvoted

Comment: The main problem with it that if a mod migrates a question, he also has to take responsibility for it. Mods very, very don't like if there is a debate about their decisions, this is why they don't like to migrate. Why the questions can't be migrated more easily by community votes, or for the approval of the target site -- well, I think nobody knows it, not even the SE decision-makers. But it is only my opinion.

Answer (score 33):

This was not a good candidate for migration.  It is on-topic at Stack Overflow, and migration is intended for off-topic questions.

> Perhaps the most compelling reason—while this question would fit very nicely on Code Review, it isn't necessarily off-topic on Stack Overflow.

This is a perfectly reasonable Stack Overflow question.  OP was not asking us to look through a page of code for problems.  OP was pointing out a specific issue and asking for advice.  That is exactly what Stack Overflow is for.  I got [11 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954297/how-to-write-getitem-cleanly) asking a similar question (which, ironically enough, was itself migrated from Programmers.SE).

> On the other hand, it seems more likely to me that the third possibility is correct. This raises the question: should I ever request migration to a site that might be a "better fit" if the question is on-topic on SO? I don't think it could *hurt*, but I'd understand if that were the policy.

Questions can be on-topic on multiple sites at once.  In that case, it's up to the asker to choose a site.  When you migrate a question, you are closing the original and creating a duplicate on a different site.  If there's no valid reason to close the original, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: And, of course, the asker may only have, or want, an account on the site they originally posted it, which leaves the question potentially orphaned.

Comment: The last paragraph answers this question about policy very directly and is really good info to be aware of. May I suggest reorganizing a little bit to feature it more prominently, perhaps toward the beginning of the answer?

Comment: @jpmc26: I've removed the discussion of whether the question was well worded, since IMHO that's beside the point, and replaced it with an executive summary of the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like unfinished code.

That sort of stuff is off-topic for Code Review.

Here's the close vote you'd get:

> off-topic because... ->
>
> Questions containing [broken code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3650) or asking for advice about [code not yet written](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3651) are off-topic, as the code is not ready for review. After the question has been edited to contain working code, we will consider reopening it.

Here's why I think it's unfinished:

- "Creating an append function"
- "how would you create a recursive append function"
- "Here's what I have so far"

The title doesn't reflect what the code does. The question is not about improving the existing implementation, it's about **expanding** the existing implementation.

Perhaps it is finished code and should be reviewed. That's okay. But in that case, the question should be edited to be less "uncertain" - Here's my problem, here's my solution, here's my tested implementation.

Before opting to migrate, please check the target site's tour.
You'd have noticed this:

[image: Don't ask about "How to add a feature"]