# Guidance on migrating questions to Code Review

Tags: discussion, migration, code-review-se, migrated-questions

I am facing problems when trying to figure out if a question should be migrated. Last year (*yes, quite a while ago*), I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764442/fine-tuning-method-listfiles) question for migration to Code Review, with a custom moderator flag. The message was the following one:

> This is asking for a code-review, which we do not do afaik. It'd be better suited for Code Review. I couldn't flag it for migration since Code Review is not listed.

It got declined with the following reason:

> declined - since the OP is asking to solve a specific problem, that makes it more SO and CR

I accepted that, and moved on with my life. Migrations have always been a bit iffy, but I mostly didn't bother flagging questions for migration; I just left comments pointing them to a community better suited for their question.

Now, today I had a discussion about [another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161736/optimizing-matlab-loop), which is quite similar to the one shown above, at least in my opinion. I was of the opinion that it shouldn't be migrated, due to the declined flag & attached reason that I received last year, however, the flag was accepted, and the question migrated.

---

What I'd like to ask now is if we have any **clear, unambiguous** guidelines regarding the migration of questions to Code Review, or if this question has already been asked & resulted in a community consensus.

Note that I've read through these two threads already:

- [A moderator declined my migration flag—what are the policies for flagging questions for migration?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288901/a-moderator-declined-my-migration-flag-what-are-the-policies-for-flagging-questi)
- [What questions are suitable for migration to Code Review, and how does the process work?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-questions-are-suitable-for-migration-to-code-review-and-how-does-the-proce)

Yet the migration of question #2 doesn't make any sense in conjunction with those two threads, as that question was on-topic for Stack Overflow as far as I know.

Comment: Is it on-topic on SO? Don't migrate. Is it off-topic on SO, but on-topic for CR, migrate.

Comment: [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Yet the 2nd question had a specific goal, and it was on topic for SO, at least from my perspective. =/

Comment: Moderators are humans, interpreting the guidelines. Different moderators can come to different conclusions, and no two questions are ever exactly the same. I migrated the latter because I saw that it would be closed as too broad on SO (so I considered it as off-topic *first*), and checked that CR accepts questions about improving performance.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This was in no way meant to criticize anybody, but I am a bit confused as to what to flag for migration in the future. =|

Comment: Keep on flagging; you were doing fine I'd say. I might have migrated the other post as well, it is rather vague and broad for SO too.

Comment: @Seth - To be honest, I'm not entirely sure where the line is for migration myself. We get a *lot* of flags asking for migration to Code Review (people tend to flag anything with phrases like "how can I improve this" for migration, justified or not). Even after reading all the discussions about this, I still don't feel like I've got a good process in place for handling these.

Comment: This question would be better suited for codereview.meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 28):

The Code Review site has a guide for this: [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778).

Notably, just because a question is on-topic on CR, it does not become off-topic on SO. Specific questions about how to improve a particular part of some code are often more suitable for SO. Particularly if they are of a theoretical nature or contain artificial examples, in which case they would be explicitly off-topic on CR.

Your first question flagged was such a question. It is not complete code, it is a single function. Therefore off-topic on CR and this could be why it was declined. It is however just fine on SO, as it has a narrow enough scope "why is this function taking so long when I do x". 
But this also means that the code is not working as the programmer intended, it has problems. Here it ends up in some gray zone between SO and CR - if the only issue was "how do I optimize this code", it may actually be fine on both sites.

Indeed the second question is very similar. It is not complete code, so by the CR site's standards it may not be well-received there.

Probably the questions were handled differently because, as indicated in comments, your flags are handled by SO moderators, who may be experts of SO but not necessarily of every other site in the SE network. Therefore they end up uncertain and your flags might get treated differently depending on how much the specific SO moderator knows about Code Review.

When in doubt if to migrate from SO to CR, I would ask on [Code Review Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/). If you get a positive answer there, you could flag with custom reason on SO and link the CR meta discussion as reference.

---

An idea for Stack Exchange as whole: perhaps it would be better if migration flags were handled by 2 moderators. One from the migrated-from site and one from the migrated-to site. And there has to be a consensus between them.

Comment: Re your last para, it seems SE sentiment is trending toward dropping migration entirely, as it's an enormous hassle to get right and only really enables a few useful things.

Comment: Note that moderators can and do ask the target site mods for a once-over when there is a question of suitability but that *requiring* a moderator on both sides of the fence to approve migrations is not going to scale. Generally, us mods know where to find one another should there be problems with specific migrations.

Comment: Note that a single function is on topic on code review as long as it compiles and behaves as expected.

Comment: I sometimes ask in the site specific chatroom if they would take a question. That is a kind-of light-weight opposed to asking on the site meta. That only works if you're into this chat thing ...